# Change existing translation?

Tags: magento2, translate

This is my translation file in a custom extension:

```
/html/xyz/app/code/FireGento/MageSetup/i18n/de_DE.csv
```

I changed one translation in that file and afterwards I executed this to gather the translations:

```
php bin/magento i18n:collect-phrases -o app/code/FireGento/MageSetup/i18n/de_DE.csv app/code/FireGento/MageSetup/
```

I also cleared the cache, but the translation is still the old term. Is that the wrong approach?

**Magento 2.2.5**

Answer (score 1):

Translations are also stored in local storage for client side translations. 
Have you cleared the local storage in you browser as well?

Comment: Yes, I have cleared that as well.